# Camera tracking, known sensor size is 1/2.3": How do I convert in mm? CMOS vs CCD?

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm learning Blender camera tracking and a bit unfamiliar with sensor sizes and how to enter the proper number in the Sensor width box under the Track tab.

I want to convert the information from manufacturers homepage but the latter just display the value in the format 1/2.3". I (and Blender) need the value in mm.

[Phantom spec page](https://www.dji.com/dk/phantom-3-adv/info)

Tried to search on the matter on the web but received varied widths between 6.16 and 6.26 mm.

(1) Any idea how to get the correct value?
(2) Also the sensor is a CMOS type and Blenders popup mentions CCD. Does this matter concerning the mm-values?

[image: Sen Width]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the three lines on the right of the "Camera" Name, you will see the size that you need (1/2.3 = 6.170)

[image]

Comment: Great, what I needed! Thanks.:)
Just from curiosity: Is there any difference between CCD and CMOS sensor types concerning the Blender camera tracking setup and does it matter at all?